# Joining data with different timestamp intervals in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp

I have two tables different with each other. The first table has this form

```
        Date1                 NGVolA
2020-11-20 12:05:19.000        10461
2020-11-20 12:14:11.000        15692
2020-11-20 12:25:53.000        20627
```

The second table has this form

```
          char_time               disch_time         FUR       char_temp         disch_temp
2020-11-20 12:06:56.600    2020-11-20 12:08:28.193    A           59               1150
2020-11-20 12:07:02.693    2020-11-20 12:09:12.177    B           61               1140
2020-11-20 12:12:18.350    2020-11-20 12:13:46.350    A           77               1160
2020-11-20 12:16:16.070    2020-11-20 12:20:38.333    A           49               1156
2020-11-20 12:19:15.520    2020-11-20 12:21:22.317    A           75               1180
2020-11-20 12:27:10.513    2020-11-20 12:30:41.287    B           147              1165
2020-11-20 12:30:11.593    2020-11-20 12:32:33.257    A           72               1195
```

What I want is to get data from the second table and aggregate them based on time intervals of the first table. e.g in the time interval between 12:05:19 and 12:10:19 of first table find how many char_time events happened and average the char_temp of them. Equally for the disch_time and disch_temp.

What I want is to get is a table like this

```
           Date1       Avg_Char_Temp_A   Char_events_A  Disch_events_A  Avg_DisCh_Temp_A      NGVolA  FUR
2020-11-20 12:05:19.000    68               2.0            1.0               1155             10461    A
2020-11-20 12:14:11.000    62               2.0            2.0               1168             15692    A
2020-11-20 12:25:53.000    72               1.0            1.0               1195             20627    A
```

What i have done so far is

```
DECLARE @StartDate nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @EndDate nvarchar(20)
     
SET @StartDate ='2020-11-20 12:00:00'
SET @EndDate =  '2020-11-20 23:59:59'
        
SELECT  
[Date1]=  a.[_TimeStamp],
[Avg_Charg_Temp_A]=avg(CASE WHEN b.[FURNACE] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (b.[charge_temperature],'0.0')) else null end),
[Char_events_A]=sum(case when b.[FURNACE] ='A' then 1.0 else null end),
[Disch_events_A]=sum(case when b.[FURNACE] ='A' then 1.0 else null end)
[Avg_DisCh_Temp_A]=avg(CASE WHEN b.[FURNACE] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (b.[ave_disch_temp],'0.0')) else null end),
[NGVolA]=sum(CASE WHEN a.[Furnace] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (a.[NG_AVG_MEAS_FLOW],'0.0')) else 0.0 end ) 
      
 FROM (select a.*, (select min(aa.[_TimeStamp])
            from fix.dbo.IBA_Data aa 
            where aa.[_TimeStamp] > a.[_TimeStamp])as next_time_2
    from fix.dbo.IBA_Data a) a 
    Left JOIN ADB.dbo.Temp_Aims b on b.[charge_time] >= a.[_TimeStamp] and b.[charge_time] < a.[next_time_2]    

WHERE 
     CONVERT(datetime, a.[_TimeStamp], 20)  BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate , 20) AND CONVERT(datetime, @EndDate , 20)     

GROUP BY
a.[_TimeStamp],

ORDER BY 
  a.[_TimeStamp]
```

The issue with the above query is that  Char_events_A and Disch_events_A are overestimated(i am getting double what i am expecting) and I  cannot aggregate  Avg_DisCh_Temp_A on _TimeStamp  and thus i cannot calculate Avg_DisCh_Temp_A.
Also keep in mind that the server i getting my data has a compatibility level SQL server 2000.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

@Chuma i am getting an error " 'MasterDetailLink' is not a recognized GROUP BY" and  "Incorrect syntax near 'WorkingData'. "

```
With MasterDetailLink as
(select 
a.[_TimeStamp], a.[NGVolA], b.[charge_time], b.[discharge_time] 
from fix.dbo.Fce_IBA_Data a inner join ALPHADB.dbo.Mill_Temp_Aims b on a.[_TimeStamp] between b.[charge_time] and b.[discharge_time] ),

WorkingData as
(select 
a.[_TimeStamp], a.[NGVolA], b.*

from MasterDetailLink a inner join ALPHADB.dbo.Mill_Temp_Aims b on a.[charge_time]=b.[charge_time] and a.[charge_time]=b.[discharge_time] )

select 
a.[_TimeStamp], 
[Avg_Charg_Temp_A]=avg(CASE WHEN b.[FURNACE] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (b.[charge_temperature],'0.0')) else null end),
[Char_events_A]=sum(case when b.[FURNACE] ='A' then 1.0 else null end),
[Disch_events_A]=sum(case when b.[FURNACE] ='A' then 1.0 else null end),
[Avg_DisCh_Temp_A]=avg(CASE WHEN b.[FURNACE] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (b.[ave_disch_temp],'0.0')) else null end),
[NGVolA]=sum(CASE WHEN a.[Furnace] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (a.[NG_AVG_MEAS_FLOW],'0.0')) else 0.0 end ) 
from WorkingData

group by a.[charge_time]

With MasterDetailLink as
(
select a.[charge_time], a.[NGVolA], b.[charge_time], b.[discharge_time] 
from fix.dbo.Fce_IBA_Data a inner join ALPHADB.dbo.Mill_Temp_Aims b on a.[_TimeStamp] between b.[charge_time] and b.[discharge_time] )
 
 WorkingData as
(
select 
a.[_TimeStamp], a.[NGVolA], b.*
from MasterDetailLink a inner join ALPHADB.dbo.Mill_Temp_Aims b on a.[charge_time]=b.[charge_time] and a.[charge_time]=b.[discharge_time]) 

select 
a.[_TimeStamp], 
[Avg_Charg_Temp_A]=avg(CASE WHEN b.[FURNACE] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (b.[charge_temperature],'0.0')) else null end),
[Char_events_A]=sum(case when b.[FURNACE] ='A' then 1.0 else null end),
[Disch_events_A]=sum(case when b.[FURNACE] ='A' then 1.0 else null end),
[Avg_DisCh_Temp_A]=avg(CASE WHEN b.[FURNACE] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (b.[ave_disch_temp],'0.0')) else null end),
[NGVolA]=sum(CASE WHEN a.[Furnace] ='A' then convert(real,isnull (a.[NG_AVG_MEAS_FLOW],'0.0')) else 0.0 end ) 
from WorkingData
group by a.[_TimeStamp]
```

Comment: Any reason to do conditional aggregation rather than just filtering by `FURNACE = 'A`? And what is the type of the date columns? `datetime` or `nvarchar`?

Comment: Also it's unclear if table2 has two different events side by side? Do you need to unpivot these into different events or are they directly related? Your current query seems to regard them as the same event. Also seems to be missing columns. **And you really have to move off compat level 80, that's ridiculous**

Answer (score 1):

For this, for simplicity, we will break it down step by step.
Our initial task should be to link the times between the parent table and child table. Since I don't have their actual names, I will call them master and detail.
So linking the times in master and detail

```
With MasterDetailLink as
(
select a.Date1, a.NGVolA, b.char_time, b.disch_time 
from master a inner join detail b
on a.Date1 between b.char_time and b.disch_time 
)
```

Now we'll just join this to the regular detail table and go from there

```
WorkingData as
(
select a.Date1, a.NGVolA, b.*
from MasterDetailLink a
 inner join detail b on a.char_time=b.char_time and a.char_time=b.disch_time 
)
```

Then from there, you can do any aggregations you need.

```
select Date1, <Aggregations here e.g. Sum(field1)>
from WorkingData
group by Date1
```

Putting it all together

```
With MasterDetailLink as
(
select a.Date1, a.NGVolA, b.char_time, b.disch_time 
from master a inner join detail b
on a.Date1 between b.char_time and b.disch_time 
), WorkingData as
(
select a.Date1, a.NGVolA, b.*
from MasterDetailLink a
 inner join detail b on a.char_time=b.char_time and a.char_time=b.disch_time 
) 
select Date1, <Aggregations here e.g. Sum(field1)>
from WorkingData
group by Date1
```

Comment: I getting some errors on your suggestion can you have a look and let me know where i made the mistake. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: This is a great way to design complex queries, @Chumai! I hope we'll see many more contributions to StackOverflow from you.

Comment: @O. Jones. Thanks. I am a freelancer so mutually beneficial to do so too. Keeps me on my toes so to speak.

Comment: @theo13. I would say that you either modify an existing with statement and deal with all your case statements there or create a new with statement that just has all the case statements you have in detail. You should be able to run it independently by itself before you summarize it. From a debugging standpoint, as you have it, it is much more difficult to figure out where the issue is. So maybe take that last query remove the aggregations to see what it looks like and if necessary make it a with statement.
Any summaries you have should just deal with known field names.

Comment: Also one last thing - I notice you have the with statement names doubled up. After the last statement following with statement definitions, all with statement names go out of scope. So essentially all those with statements are made to support the last statement or any with statements before the last select/delete/insert statement. That may be part of your error.